# Freehdl (work.electricalsystem is undeclared)

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to model two BJT switches specifically NPN and PNP transistors from source code found online but keep coming up against the same error.

```
work.electricalsystem is undeclared.
```

I am simulating using freehdl on Xubuntu.

The codes are:

```
--TEST BENCH
use std.textio.all;
use work.electrical_systems.all;

entity NPN_BJT is
port (terminal t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 : electrical)
end NPN_BJT;

architecture structure of NPN_BJT is

-- Component declarations need to be made here
quantity vr1 across ir1 through.t5 to t4;
quantity vc1 across ic1 through.t4;
quantity vc2 across ic2 through.t2;
quantity vbr across ibr through.t4 to t3;
quantity vrc across irc through.t1 to t2;
quantity vcc across icc through.t1;

begin
sqr : sqr_comp

generic map(0.0, 5.0, 10us)

port map(t5, electrical'reference);

cres : vrc == irc a 1.0e3;

bres : vbr == ihr a 2.2e3;

csrc : vcc == 10.0;

res1 : vr1 == ir1 * 1.0;

cap1 : ic1 == 1.0e-6 * vc1'dot;

cap2 : ic2 == 1 0e-9 * vc2'dot;

brk : break vc1 => 0.0, vc2 => 10.0;

bjt : bjt_npn_comp
generic map (isat => 14.34e-15, vaf => 74.03, bf => 65.62, hr => 9.715,
rc => 1.0, cjc0 => 9.393e-12, mjc => 0.3416, vjc => 0.75, cje0 => 22.02e-12,
mje => 0.377, vje => 0.75, tr => 58.98e-9, tf => 408.8e-12, rb => 10.0)
port map(electrical reference,t3,t2);
end architecture structure;
```

and...

```
--TEST BENCH
use std.textio.all;
use work.electricalsystem.all;

entity PNP_BJT is
end PNP_BJT;

architecture structure of PNP_BJT is
terminal t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 : electrical ;

-- Component declarations need to be made here
quantity vbr across ibr through t4 to t3;
quantity vrc across irc through t1 to t2;
quantity vcc across icc through t1;
quantity vout across iout through t2;
quantity vr1 across ir1 through t5 to t4;
quantity vc1 across ic1 through t4;

begin
sqr : sqr_comp

generic map(0.0, 5.0, 10us)

port map(electrical'reference, t5);

cres : vrc irc * 1.0e3;

bres : vbr == ibr * 2.2e3;

csrc : vcc == -10.0;

cout : iout == 1.0e-9 * vout'dot;

res1 : vr1 == ir1 * 1.0;

cap1 : ic1 == 1.0e-6 * vc1'dot;

brk : break vc1 => -5.0, vout => 0.0;

bjt : bjt_pnp_comp
generic map (isat => 14.34e-15, vaf => 74.03, bf => 65.62, br => 9.715,
rc => 1.0, cjc0 => 9.393e-12, mjc => 0.3416, vjc => 0.75, cje0 => 22.02e-12,
mje => 0.377, vje => 0.75, tr => 58.98e-9, tf => 408.8e-12, rb => 10.0)
port map(electrical'reference,t3,t2);
end architecture structure;
```

Please help with this error.

Thanks.

Comment: You are using two different packages, `use work.electrical_systems.all;` and `use work.electricalsystem.all;`. Do they both exist?

Comment: Actually the code was originally... `use work.electricalsystem.all` but I changed it to `use work.electrical_systems.all` but in both cases the use directive is undeclared. Any ideas? Also might you know where I can get BJT codes either in vhdl or verilog that actually compile? Most of the ones online are overly complex and compile like rubbish.

Comment: You won't find BJTs in VHDL at all - or Verilog either. VHDL-AMS might do what you want but I don't know enough about it to comment. If you want to model BJTs you're probably better off with SPICE.

Comment: Hi, SPICE was exactly what I needed thanks. Now do you know of any freeware to convert SPICE netlist to HDL? This would make my projects go a lot faster. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a file "electricalsystem.vhd" or so, for sure a file containing "entity electricalsystem ...." and "archicture *** of electricalsystem" and compile that one into work before your bjt models.

As others pointed out, VHDL is an awkward choice for analog modeling. VerilogA, VerilogAMS, SystemVerilog are better choices on system level. For analog simulation you'd obviously have to go for some spice flavor, spectre, ...

For those I guess that you wont need to translate your vhdl model. It should be far easier to find plenty of models in those languages ...

Comment: Actually, I decided to go with SPICE. I managed to model my project in record time. Simulation runs great.